# Create a spinner programmatically in Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to create a spinner without using XML. I am new in android and my knowledge is limited. By now I have this code (see above) and I want my spinner in one of the tabs of my `TabActivity`.
There is no obvious error but when I open my activity the tab is empty. I would appreciate some help.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("one");
    spinnerArray.add("two");
    spinnerArray.add("three");
    spinnerArray.add("four");
    spinnerArray.add("five");

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

}
```

Comment: What does it mean you want a "spinner in on of the tabs"? Can you show an example of what you are trying to get?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to add the `Spinner` to a layout.

First create a `container` for the `Spinner` and then create the `Spinner` and add it to your `container`. Next set content of you `Activity` to your `container`.

This could be done like this, in your `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("one");
    spinnerArray.add("two");
    spinnerArray.add("three");
    spinnerArray.add("four");
    spinnerArray.add("five");

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    layout.addView(spinner);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify: if the `Spinner` isn't added to the content of the `Activity` inside a layout, it isn't visible, so that's why you don't get any errors or anything, because there isn't any errors in your code, per se ;-)

Comment: i use a TabActivity and my activity layout has a TabHost. I want to use the spinner only in one tab and thats why i didnt put a spinner in the xml. How is it possible to create another layout(activity_my) to put the spinner and use it only in this tab??

Comment: To add the spinner to a specific fragment you would need to add the spinner to the specific fragments layout instead of the activity's layout. If this doesn't make sense open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        // The following can also be done using a loop
        ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerArray.add("one");
        spinnerArray.add("two");
        spinnerArray.add("three");
        spinnerArray.add("four");
        spinnerArray.add("five");


        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        layout.addView(spinner);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
    }
```