# Creating dynamic spinners and getting value of every spinner, Whenever a spinner item changed, get all spinner values

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm developing a e-com app. I'm trying to create dynamic spinner. Spinner is dependent upon product attributes. I'm able to create spinners also mapped data on them but I want to get all spinners selected item whenever a spinner change its data so I can match to correct variant of product.

Here is my code snippet

```
final List<Attribute> attributes = product_.getAttributes();
        for (i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = (ArrayList<String>) attributes.get(i).getOptions();
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                }
            });
            dynamicProductProperties.addView(spinner);

        }
```

Comment: Why did you use OnItemSelectedListener in loop ?

Comment: i don't know the id of spinner..

Comment: What's the relation between ID and Loop and you can just go to the related xml to check the id...

Comment: or if there is no id, just set id yourself.

Comment: i've set a id and also put on select listner outside... but how to get every spinner value when one spinner changes.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your problem. How is your design ? Don't you have only one spinner ?

Comment: i have multiple spinners with depends upon attribute array size

Comment: Then you must add them to your layout and set some ids for example spn1, spn2 etc. If you don't add them, how can you see them in your app ?

Comment: I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119841/create-a-spinner-programmatically-android) helps you.

Comment: I m creating spinners dynamically.. I got success in that.. above link is for creating dynamic spinner.. which was not my question

Comment: I got it, you did. But if you don't add them to layout, You cannot be able to see.

Comment: I'm able to see. `dynamicProductProperties.addView(spinner);` this line of code add spinner to my linear layout

Comment: So am i right, when any spinner item selected, you want to keep value ?

Comment: Did you tried spinner.getId() to get your spinners ids ?

Comment: yes ids are not the problem

Comment: You can use implements OnItemSelectedListener in your Activity class. And override methods outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to set same instance of OnItemSelectListener to your all spinners. Let your activity or fragment implement OnItemSelectListener then call `spinner.setOnItemSelectListener(this);`

In ***onItemSelected*** method you can run this code to have selecteds.

```
    ArrayList<String> selectedList = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < dynamicProductProperties.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = dynamicProductProperties.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof Spinner){
           String selected = (String) ((Spinner) view).getSelectedItem();
            selectedList.add(TextUtils.isEmpty(selected) ? "" : selected);
        }
    }
```

Good luck

Emre

Comment: looks like elegant solution.. let me try